# how to cropp image in titanium by programming?

Tags: titanium-mobile

I am implementing one iphone/Android application using Titanium in which I want to crop the image.Please check below flow which I have implemented.
1)Open Camara
2)Take photo
3)Display photo in the application
4)Crop photo with some area

I have implemented above 3 steps but for croping I am facing issue.I have tried below code for croping.

var file = Titanium.Filesystem.getFile(header1).toBlob();
var cropped = file.imageAsCropped(10, 10, 290, 232);

var croImg = Ti.UI.createImageView({
    image: file,
    top:0,
    left : 0,
    width:290,
    height:232
});

win1.add(croImg);

But i can't get sucess. IF you give me advice then would be appriciate.

Thanks

Comment: if my answer solved your problem please remember to mark as top answer so others will know this solved the issue. if not please add more comments to say what the issue is so it can be solved

Answer (score 1):

Theres another way to do it with a separate imageView smaller than the original images and setting what portion to display. check out this link that gives a good example:

http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/72431/crop-imageview

Comment: Thanks for your answer but in this solution it seems images is croped but acctually its not croped...I want to crop image and post on to the server...

Comment: the cropped image is converted to an image blob and stored in a var.  see : var croppedImage = cropView.toImage(); this is then displayed in the view